# javascript jquery datatables undefined is not a function

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, datatables

I'm following the jquery datatables tutorial for adding child tables to display after a click.

```js
var table = $("#equipment_table").dataTable(
{
     "paging":   false,
     "ordering": false,
     "info":     false
});
$('#equipment_table tbody').on('click', 'td .pickup_button', function(){
    alert("clickee");
    var tr = $(this).closest('tr');
    var row = table.row(tr);
    if(row.child.isShown()){
        //open , close it
        row.child.hide();
        tr.removeClass('shown');
    }else {
        row.child( buildChild(tr.attr('id'))).show();
        tr.addClass('shown');
    }
});
```

and here's the html button definition in php

```php
    echo '<td> <button class="delivery_button" id="'.$eid.'"> Delivery Status </button> </td>';
    echo '<td> <button class="pickup_button" id="'.$eid.'"> Pickup Status </button> </td>';
    echo '</tr>';
}
echo '</tbody>';
```

after getting the click listener to work, i get this error

```
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function
```

on `var row = table.row(tr);` line

Comment: Any messages in the console and does it work if you remove everything except the `alert()`? If it doesn't you should check and post your html instead of the php.

Comment: Where does `table` get set? `var row = table.row(tr);`

Comment: @bloodyKnuckles that was actually the problem, table wasn't set. after i set it tho, the clicking works but the jquery but something is undefined. and i get a error. I will update my question

Comment: Where does the `buildChild` function come from?

Comment: its a function I wrote, it reutrns a HTML object

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's just a case issue. You should define your variable `table` like this:

```
var table = $("#equipment_table").DataTable(
{
  "paging":   false,
  "ordering": false,
  "info":     false
});
```

Notice how this uses `.DataTable()` rather than `.dataTable()`

Here's what it says in the [API Docs for DataTables](https://datatables.net/manual/api):

> It is important to note the difference between `$( selector ).DataTable()` and `$( selector ).dataTable()`. The former returns a DataTables API instance, while the latter returns a jQuery object.

Since you are getting back a jQuery object rather than an API instance, the method `.row()` is undefined, and that is what causes the error to be thrown.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Check your version.  In case the above answer doesn't work for anyone stumbling on here (it didn't for me), calling the API this way only works with DataTables 1.10.x and up.  I was pounding my head against a wall and realized I was on a 1.9.x branch.

Answer (score 0):

Notice how this uses .DataTable() rather than .dataTable() and you should use like
`var tr = $(this).closest('tr');
                        var row = table.row( tr );
                        if ( row.child.isShown() ) {
                            // This row is already open - close it
                            row.child.hide();
                            tr.removeClass('shown');
                        }
                        else {
                            row.child(format(row.data())).show();
                            tr.addClass('shown');
                        }`